# Debian Multi-Arch: what is the difference between multi-arch: same and multi-arch: foreign

Tags: debian, packaging, apt

The concept of Multi-arch enables you to install packages from more than one architecture on the same machine. But what is the difference between packages which are `Multi-Arch: same` to packages which are `Multi-Arch: foreign`?

Answer (score 2):

`Multi-arch: same` package can be installed side by side with the same package of a different architecture on the same machine. For example, if `libfoo` is of `Multi-arch: same`, then `libfoo:amd64` and `libfoo:i386` can be installed on the same machine at the same time.

`Multi-arch: foreign` is a package that can satisfy decency for package of different architecture. For example, perhaps our `libfoo` depends on `libfoo-data`. If `libfoo:data` is of `Multi-arch: foreign`, it can be installed once and satisfy both `libfoo:amd64` and `libfoo:i386` dependencies.